# Is there a good strategy to create complex nested SObjects in JavaScript for INSERT in Apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, dml

I'm implementing frequently Aura Components which must INSERT nested SObjects.

As an example imagine you have this simplified data-model, references are lookups:

- ItemGroup__c
- Order__c

  - OrderItem__c

So we have a lookup called Order__c on OrderItem__c. Also we have a lookup called ItemGroup__c on OrderItem__c.

I can create a list of Order__c[], ItemGroup[] and OrderItem__c[] and bypass that to apex. Having multiple related Orders, ItemGroups and Items per insert, I can NOT know the Ids of the parent objects Order__c and ItemGroup__c in JavaScript in advance to populate the lookups right in the helper of the Aura Component

In the example the model is very simple. Imagine a layered network of 8 to 12 nested/related SObjects in reality. The whole insert is burden. On the other hand it is a simple thing, no rocket science.

Currently my concept is to have per use-case a complex logic in Apex to step-by-step insert the network starting at the parents, keeping the new Ids and diving layer-by-layer down to the child objects setting the correct freshly inserted parent Id.

**I absolutely do not like it.**

I am looking for a reusable pattern to bypass something like a nested JSON to Apex, having one generic implementation to insert whole networks of nested objects and let one generic logic figure out the right parent ids for all child objects automatically.

Doing it over and over in Apex again is time-consuming, error-prone and feels like a stupid thing necessary to do endless times.

Questions:

- Has anyone implemented something like that?
- Is there any standard functionality helping to get it done?
- Is it worth to try, or has anyone tried it and given up, because of unforeseen challenges?
- Is there a trick, like populating a list of child objects in the refence-name-list? E.g. Order__c.OrderItems__r of type OrderItem__c[]? Something to INSERT nested like query with a subselect query?